# Another little Riley, beware of the silent 'H'

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

My prefix is a part of speech,
we use it every day.
My infix is a remedy,
used by people from the cities away.
My suffix is an object you kick,
without hatred I'd say.
And overall I'm not visual,
but information in another way.

Comment: I can't wait until this Riley trend is over.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your word is

> verbal

Prefix is a part of speech, we use it every day

> Verb

My infix is a remedy used by people from the cities away

> (H) erb, use the silent H from the title here

My suffix is an object you kick, without hatred I'd say

> Bal(l)

Overall not visual, but information in another way

> Verbal